# Alignat environment with \left( \right)

Tags: equations, alignment, alignat

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{1}
a ={}& b \left( c \left( \frac{d}{e} + f \right) + \notag\\
& g \left( \frac{h}{i} + j \right) \right)
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

I think this code doesn't compile because the first `\left(` and the last `\right)` are in different lines, which LaTeX obviously considers two different equations.

Is there a clean way to get it running while still making use of the automatic scaling provided by `\left( \right)`?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: @Mico Short response: Thanks.

Comment: You need no `\left` and `\right` with those terms. May you please make a “real world” example?

Comment: @egreg I'm trying to write equations that are half a page long at most. Didn't think it would matter, but I can make it more "real word" (while also less "minimal" ofc).

Comment: @egreg updated, hope its usable now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

- with use of `\left(`, `\right`) (see use of `right.` and `left.`, and
- with use of `\biggl(` and `\biggr)`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{1}
a ={}& b \left( c \left( \frac{d}{e} + f \right) + \notag \right.\\
& \left.g \left( \frac{h}{i} + j \right) \right)
\end{alignat}

\begin{alignat}{1}
a ={}& b \biggl( c \left( \frac{d}{e} + f \right) + \notag \\
& g \left( \frac{h}{i} + j \right) \biggr)
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was aware of option 2, but not of option 1. Unfortunately still some manual fiddling involved, but if this is as good as it's gonna get, I'll take it. Thanks!